# 24 hour conversion to decimal

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function

I figured it out _ I had to change the cell format to number and add *24

Using the following 
=SUM(MOD(C6-B6,1)+(E6-D6)) I get a correct 24hr sum of time (9.30) however I need that in decimal format so I use
=(E6-INT(E6))*24 to convert it to (9.5)

I'm having problems trying to combine into one formula - any help would be appreciated.

I'm having problems figuring hours worked, with a 24 hour day formula that accounts for swing and graveyard 
this is a 4 column layout - example below (I only need to figure totals hours worked minus Lunch)

example:

in 20:30   out (lunch) 01:00    in(lunch) 01:30     end of shift 06:30

Answer should be: should be 4.5+5 = 9.5 hours worked 
However I'm having trouble with 20:30pm to 01:00am value

thank you in advance!

Comment: non 24 hr example: =SUM(B4-A4)+(D4-C4)                                    11:30 16:00 16:30 20:00 = 8:00

Comment: @Tom please [edit] & add it to your question, not as a comment. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use the `MOD` function within your `SUM` function you can calculate the time which crosses midnight.

[image]